# A row number as id in the results of an Sphinx Search

Tags: mysql, search, row, sphinx

Is it possible to return the row number as an ID?
In my view where i merge my tables I can't make a unique ID because I need to create left
joins to store every value:

```
CREATE VIEW
sphinx
AS
SELECT

company.company_id,
company.company_name,
company.company_keywords,

company_address.address_street,
company_address.address_number,
company_address.address_telephone,
company_address.address_fax,
company_address.address_email,
company_address.address_website,
company_address.address_authorized,

company_contact.contact_name,
company_contact.contact_surname,
company_contact.contact_telephone,
company_contact.contact_mobilephone,
company_contact.contact_fax,
company_contact.contact_email,

company_page.page_content,
company_page.page_description,
company_page.page_keywords

FROM company
LEFT JOIN company_address ON company.company_id = company_address.company_id
LEFT JOIN company_page ON company.company_id = company_page.company_id
LEFT JOIN company_contact ON company.company_id = company_contact.company_id
```

When I receive the row number i can just do SELECT * FROM sphinx LIMIT 1 OFFSET rowNumber
to get the information of that row.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it the following way

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
(@rownum:=@rownum + 1) as rownumber, q.*
FROM (
SELECT
* /*shortened for readability*/
FROM company
LEFT JOIN company_address ON company.company_id = company_address.company_id
LEFT JOIN company_page ON company.company_id = company_page.company_id
LEFT JOIN company_contact ON company.company_id = company_contact.company_id
, (select @rownum:=0) r
) q
) asdf
WHERE rownumber BETWEEN 2 AND 3 /*or whatever*/
```

EDIT: To explain a bit more:

This one

```
, (select @rownum:=0) r
```

declares and initializes the variable which will serve as our rownumber.
If you would include `@rownum` in the `SELECT` list of your inner most query, you would get a column which has the value 0 in each row.

So you make this inner query a subquery and just add 1 to the @rownum variable.
With only this

```
SELECT 
(@rownum:=@rownum + 1) as rownumber, q.*
FROM (
SELECT
* /*shortened for readability*/
FROM company
LEFT JOIN company_address ON company.company_id = company_address.company_id
LEFT JOIN company_page ON company.company_id = company_page.company_id
LEFT JOIN company_contact ON company.company_id = company_contact.company_id
, (select @rownum:=0) r
) q
```

you would already have a rownumber. Since you can't refer to the column alias `rownumber` in the `WHERE` clause, you would have to write something like

```
WHERE (@rownum:=@rownum + 1) BETWEEN 2 AND 3 /*or whatever*/
```

but this would lead to false results, because the `@rownum` variable would get incremented again and your rownumber would be like

```
2
4
6
```

and so on. Therefore you have to put it in another subquery and then you can "limit" your query via the WHERE clause.

Any more questions?

Comment: It really works.. THANK YOU!! Can you please explain a littlebit what's going on?